# How can I unit test JS that uses a REST API?

Tags: jquery, rest, qunit, sinon

So here's the deal: I have a single `iframe` in mypage.html. Using jQuery, I look at `http://mysite.com/rest/foo` (an exposed REST service) and get a XML response back, which contained a url. I set the iframe's `src` attribute to that URL.

The question, now, is how would I unit test this (using [QUnit](http://qunitjs.com/) and [Sinon.js](http://sinonjs.org/))? I'm very new to unit testing in general, so I would like to hear some more experienced opinions and examples.

**script.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function setUrl(url) 
    {
        $('iframe').attr('src', url);
    }

    function throwError() 
    {
        // Error handling
    }   

    function myCallback(response) 
    {
        var url = $(response).find("url");

        if (!url.text()) throwError();
        else setUrl(url.text());
    }

    function bar(restLocation, callback) 
    {       
        $.get("http://mysite.com/rest/" + restLocation, callback);
    }

    bar("foo", myCallback);
});
```

In particular, I'm wondering about the following things:

1. I'm guessing I need to expose all of these functions to the global namespace in order to test them. Is this absolutely necessary, or is there a way to test them while still in the `document.ready()` function?
2. Which function(s) should I test? `bar()` really only does one thing: make an AJAX call to /rest/foo/ and then call `myCallback`, while the others are helper methods (if I were writing this in Java or C#, they would probably be private)... should I test them too? The end user (the one who's viewing mypage.html) technically doesn't even have a choice of which REST address to point to.
3. I imagine some suitable test cases might be

   - If a valid restLocation is passed to `bar()`, the iframe src should be set.
   - If an invalid restLocation is passed, the error must be handled (in the form of loading a 404 or something)
   - If the server is down, handle the error.
   - Anything else?

Unfortunately, if I try to do `$('iframe').attr('src')`, it returns `undefined`. If I try using `prop()`, I get an empty string. How would I check to see if `src` has been set properly?

Sorry for the long question. I'm just quite a bit confused on what kind of tests make a "good" unit test, and how one would test things in this situation.

Comment: Is it really a unit test if you're calling a REST API?  If this were any other thing, I'd separate out the code that processes the results from the REST call and the code that actually makes the REST call; and then Unit test the code that processes the results. There's a tenant of unit testing that seems applicable: Don't test code you don't own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should put the function passing into the `read` function into a named function, so you can call it like this

```
$(document).ready(myFunction)
```

Now you call myFunction into your test without the need to mock the `$.ready` function.

The test will look like this:

```
test( sets the iFrameUrl", function() {
  var server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
  server.respondWith('responseUrl');
  server.autoRespond = true;
  $('body').append('iframe')
  myFunction();
  equal($('iframe').attr('src'), 'responseUrl', 'iframe url')
})
```

Comment: Thanks. In the end I just refactored the whole thing and took some of your suggestions for the tests.